# Google Maps marker has to be clicked twice to register

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Sometimes, when I click on a marker once, all of the markers disappear for a second and reappear. Then I have to click again on a marker for the click event to register and the Info-Box to display. I am pretty sure this is also the reason why my markers don't disappear when I call the clearMarkers() function if I haven't already clicked on a marker. Here is my code:

```
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var cat = "restaurants, All";

var C = [...];
var D = [...];


function initMap() {
    // Create a map object and specify the Div element to display it on
    loc = {lat: 41.902783, lng: 12.496366};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: loc,
        zoom: 14,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    // Displays all of the markers when page loads, all restaurants
    getJsonData('yelpdata.php?cat=restaurants, All&lat='+loc.lat+'&lng='+loc.lng, map);

    var filtersPanel = document.getElementById('filtersPanel');
    var textField1 = document.getElementById('userInput');

    // Displays the markers according the value the user is typing (cat)
    function useValue() {
        clearMarkers();

        var textFieldVal = textField1.value;
        var ind = findIndex(textFieldVal);

        if (ind != -1) {
            cat = D[ind];
        }
        getJsonData('yelpdata.php?cat='+cat+'&lat='+loc.lat+'&lng='+loc.lng, map);
    }

    // Text box event handlers
    //textField1.oninput = useValue;
    textField1.onchange = useValue;
    textField1.addEventListener("awesomplete-selectcomplete", useValue);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        latitude = event.latLng.lat();
        longitude =  event.latLng.lng();
        newCenter = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
        map.setCenter(newCenter);
        loc = newCenter;

        useValue();
    });

    var autocomplete = new Awesomplete(textField1, {
        list: C,
        filter: Awesomplete.FILTER_STARTSWITH,
        minChars: 1,
        autoFirst: true
    });

    // Displays the filters panel in the top-left of the screen
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(filtersPanel);
}


function findIndex(cat) {
    for(var i=0; i<C.length; i++) {
        if(C[i] == cat)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function clearMarkers() {
    // Clears the markers from the map and array

    for (var i=0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray = [];
}


function getJsonData(url, map) {
    // Using AJAX to get the JSON data from the 'yelpdata.php' file and display markers with info-boxes on the map

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest; // the main object to request the XML

    request.onreadystatechange = function() { // when the request changes state
        if (request.readyState == 4) { // success, we have recieved the XML object from sending the request

            var json = request.responseText;
            var obj = JSON.parse(json);

            var numMarkers = obj.businesses.length;
            document.getElementById("numResults").innerHTML = numMarkers + " results";

            for (var i = 0; i < obj.businesses.length; i++) {
                (function(index) {

                    // Getting all of the attributes for each business from the JSON
                    var business = obj.businesses[index];
                    var name = business.name;

                    var catArr = business.categories;
                    var catStr = "";
                    for (j=0; j < catArr.length; j++) {
                        if (j == 0) {
                            catStr += catArr[j].title;
                        } else if (j > 0) {
                            catStr += ", " + catArr[j].title;
                        }
                    }

                    var reviews = business.review_count;
                    var rating = business.rating;
                    var address = business.location.address1 + ", " + business.location.city + ", " + business.location.state;
                    var coord = {lat: business.coordinates.latitude,
                                lng: business.coordinates.longitude};
                    var url = business.url;
                    var img_url = business.image_url;



                    // Creating the info-box
                    var markerInfo = document.createElement('div');

                    var title = document.createElement('strong'); // name
                    title.textContent = name;
                    var text0 = document.createElement('text'); // categories
                    text0.textContent = catStr;
                    var text1 = document.createElement('text'); // address
                    text1.textContent = address;
                    var text2 = document.createElement('text'); // reviews
                    text2.textContent = reviews + " reviews";
                    var text3 = document.createElement('text'); // rating
                    text3.textContent = rating + " stars";

                    // Appending the text to the info-box
                    markerInfo.appendChild(title);
                    markerInfo.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                    markerInfo.appendChild(text0);
                    markerInfo.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                    markerInfo.appendChild(text1);
                    markerInfo.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                    markerInfo.appendChild(text2);
                    markerInfo.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                    markerInfo.appendChild(text3);

                    // create the marker on its according position and append into array
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: coord
                    });

                    // change the opacity of the markers according to rating
                    if (rating >= 4) {
                        marker.setOpacity(1.0);
                    } else if (rating >= 2.5 && rating < 4) {
                        marker.setOpacity(0.8);
                    } else if (rating < 2.5) {
                        marker.setOpacity(0.6);
                    }

                    // set the info-box to the marker on click
                    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        console.log("Registering");
                        infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                    markersArray.push(marker);
                })(i);
            }
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', url); // initialize the request
    request.send(); // send the request

}
```

Comment: could it be that they disappear when you click because the first line in your useValue is removing them and readding?  Try removing the clear and getJsonData calls from the useValue function

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because I'm not calling useValue() when I click on a marker.

Comment: Then put a debug stop in your clear method and track when it being called.  I have a feeling your getting a map click along with your marker click.  Your calling the useValue each time the map is clicked which is clearing your stuff.

Comment: You are right, but this isn't the problem. The problem is that the markers do not get registered the first time I click them, but they do when I click on them a second time. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: I dont understand why you are calling the useValue when the map is clicked.  As i said earlier, i think that is your problem.  try removing the useValue call from within the map click.  I dont know why clicking on the map requires you to clear everything.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if this helps...

In this batch of code you are building the infobox content but not setting it until the click event.

```
       // set the info-box to the marker on click
       infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
       marker.addListener('click', function() {
           console.log("Registering");
           infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
           infoWindow.open(map, marker);
       });
```

try moving the line that sets the content outside the click event.  you should only need to set it once anyway

```
       infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
       infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
       marker.addListener('click', function() {
           console.log("Registering");
           infoWindow.open(map, marker);
       });
```